# toString method to remove too many whitespaces

Tags: java, stack, tostring

I have a text editor buffer hw assignment with 2 stacks (`left` and `right`). Everything works the way it's supposed to for the most part. But the trouble i'm having is that it's returning too many white spaces. I'm specifically trying to fill in the `toString()` method to return the text. 
for example the return text prints:

```
 T h e r e i s g r a n d e u r i n t h i s v i e w o f l i f e ,
```

There are single spaces between the letters, and double spaces between each word. How do I remove the whitespaces between the letters, while only removing 1 whitespace between the words so that my string returns:

```
There is grandeur in this view of life,
```

---

```
public class Buffer {
    private Stack<Character> left;  // chars left of cursor
    private Stack<Character> right; // chars right of cursor

    // Create an empty buffer.
    public Buffer() {
        left = new Stack<Character>();
        right = new Stack<Character>();
    }

    // Insert c at the cursor position.
    public void insert(char c) {
        left.push(c);
    }

    // Delete and return the character at the cursor.
    public char delete() {
        if (!right.isEmpty()){
            return right.pop();
        }else return 0;
    }

    // Move the cursor k positions to the left.
    public void left(int k) {
        while (!left.isEmpty() && --k >= 0){
            right.push(left.pop());
        }
    }

    // Move the cursor k positions to the right.
    public void right(int k) {
        while (!right.isEmpty() && --k >=0){
            left.push(right.pop());
        }
    }

    // Return the number of characters in the buffer.
    public int size() {
        return left.size()+right.size();
    }

    // Return a string representation of the buffer with a "|" character (not 
    // part of the buffer) at the cursor position.
    public String toString() {

        String a = (left+"|"+right);


        return a;
    }

    // Test client (DO NOT EDIT).
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Buffer buf = new Buffer();
        String s = "There is grandeur in this view of life, with its " 
            + "several powers, having been originally breathed into a few " 
            + "forms or into one; and that, whilst this planet has gone " 
            + "cycling on according to the fixed law of gravity, from so " 
            + "simple a beginning endless forms most beautiful and most " 
            + "wonderful have been, and are being, evolved. ~ " 
            + "Charles Darwin, The Origin of Species";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            buf.insert(s.charAt(i));
        }
        buf.left(buf.size());
        buf.right(97);
        s = "by the Creator ";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            buf.insert(s.charAt(i));
        }
        buf.right(228);
        buf.delete();
        buf.insert('-');
        buf.insert('-');
        buf.left(342);
        StdOut.println(buf);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should show your best good faith attempt to solve your problem with your questions as per the rules of this site. Please also have a look at [How do I ask and answer Homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852). This information is valid whether or not the question is for homework or home work (self-study).

Comment: What is the code to your toString() method?

Comment: hint: identify if there are two space or a single space .  *java.lang.String.toCharArray()* (Note: there are better ways eg. Regex! but might be too much for a starter) . then replace 2 space with 1 space , and 1 space with empty string *""*

Comment: i have updated the post with a link to the github gist. i'm still new to to java and here for that matter, i will follow rules accordingly from now on.  i'm not asking for an answer, but maybe a nudge in the right direction so i can figure it out for myself.

Comment: i have tried string.replace("\\s+","") but it removes all spaces.

Comment: @PinTacular I've tested the code. Works just fine for me, except that the entire output is reverse.

Comment: @Paul could you elaborate a little bit? i'm running it in intellij and its not coming out the way it's supposed to.

Comment: @PinTacular neither for me, but there aren't too many spaces, it's just all reverse. The entire string is printed from last to first character instead of first to last character

Comment: @Paul thats odd, its printing out in the correct direction for me, just that there are too may spaces. i've attached an image to show what i have. http://imgur.com/A2lopuW

Comment: @PinTacular well, in that case either the code on github isn't the latest version, or there's some weird bug in the `StdOut`-class. Btw., that class is missing...

Comment: @Paul yeah, its just the lib that the school requires us to use. Stdout.print() == System.out.print();

Answer (score 1):

You code relies on the `toString()` method of `Stack`. You should not do that unless the formatting is well-defined, and it is not well-defined for `java.util.Stack`, although it outputs the same way as other collection classes, i.e. `[value1, value2, value3]`.

See [this IDEONE](https://ideone.com/6182eD) for an example of the output (once I replaced `StdOut` with `System.out`):

```
[]|[s, e, i, c, e, p, S,  , f, o,  , n, i, g, i, r, O,  , e, h, T,  , ,, n, i, w, r, a, D,  , s, e, l, r, a, h, C,  , -, -,  , ., d, e, v, l, o, v, e,  , ,, g, n, i, e, b,  , e, r, a,  , d, n, a,  , ,, n, e, e, b,  , e, v, a, h,  , l, u, f, r, e, d, n, o, w,  , t, s, o, m,  , d, n, a,  , l, u, f, i, t, u, a, e, b,  , t, s, o, m,  , s, m, r, o, f,  , s, s, e, l, d, n, e,  , g, n, i, n, n, i, g, e, b,  , a,  , e, l, p, m, i, s,  , o, s,  , m, o, r, f,  , ,, y, t, i, v, a, r, g,  , f, o,  , w, a, l,  , d, e, x, i, f,  , e, h, t,  , o, t,  , g, n, i, d, r, o, c, c, a,  , n, o,  , g, n, i, l, c, y, c,  , e, n, o, g,  , s, a, h,  , t, e, n, a, l, p,  , s, i, h, t,  , t, s, l, i, h, w,  , ,, t, a, h, t,  , d, n, a,  , ;, e, n, o,  , o, t, n, i,  , r, o,  , s, m, r, o, f,  , w, e, f,  , a,  , o, t, n, i,  , r, o, t, a, e, r, C,  , e, h, t,  , y, b,  , d, e, h, t, a, e, r, b,  , y, l, l, a, n, i, g, i, r, o,  , n, e, e, b,  , g, n, i, v, a, h,  , ,, s, r, e, w, o, p,  , l, a, r, e, v, e, s,  , s, t, i,  , h, t, i, w,  , ,, e, f, i, l,  , f, o,  , w, e, i, v,  , s, i, h, t,  , n, i,  , r, u, e, d, n, a, r, g,  , s, i,  , e, r, e, h, T]
```

The entire string is reversed, as people have been telling you, and there are brackets (`[]`) and comma-space separators (`,`).

If you don't see that, then you're likely not using `java.util.Stack`, but some homegrown implementation.

Anyway, the solution is to fix your `toString` implementation to not rely on the `toString()` of `Stack`, because even if it didn't output spaces, you'd still get bad results if the "cursor" is in the middle of your text.

If you are using `java.util.Stack`, you should create a `StringBuilder()`, then iterate `left` and append each character, append the `|`, then iterate `right` using `right.listIterator(right.size())` and iterating backwards using `hasPrevious()` and `previous()` to append characters.

Comment: you are correct, it isnt using the standard java.util.stack. but the princeton version of stack (if theres a difference). the output i get looks like
http://imgur.com/A2lopuW
i HAVE to fill in the toString method, because its what the professor asked of us.

Comment: *"i HAVE to fill in the toString method"* Yes, that's what I was saying too. You have to change *your* `toString()` method to something that works, which means to not use the `Stack.toString()` method, as you're implicitly doing right now with the expression `left+"|"+right`.

Comment: ah, ok i get it. is there a direction you could point me in on how to achieve this? again, not looking for an answer, but some direction on which way to go from here.

Comment: @PinTacular Yes, I can direct you. Read the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: so i would iterate through the stack and put it into a string (newString).

new for loop to iterate through new string{
if newString.contains "  " (<-- 2 spaces) { replace with " " (<-- 1 space)}
else if newString.contains " "(<-- 1 space), replace with "" (<--no spaces)}

is my logic correct here?

Comment: @PinTacular No. If you iterate the *characters* of the two stacks, and append them to a `StringBuilder` (not a String), you'd be done. There'd be no extra spaces to remove, because they were never appended. Right now, the extra spaces are inserted by the `Stack.toString()` method, and you won't be calling that anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Either fix your algorithm (preferred), or here's a simple "quick and dirty" way:

```
String fixed = str.replaceAll("(?<! ) ", "");
```

The match regex means "space characters that are not preceded by a space character".